# NDK version is UNKNOWN

Tags: java, android-studio

Please help:(

Log:

Gradle sync failed: Could not determine artifacts for com.github.ratty3697:android-smart-animation-library:1.6: Skipped due to earlier error (52 s 278 ms)

NDK Resolution Outcome: Project settings: Gradle model version=5.4.1, NDK version is UNKNOWN

[My settings gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZJKO.png)
[Offline work off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kySz.png)

Comment: Its seems the your setting of offline Gradle not letting you connect to the library you are trying to use for animation.

Comment: Please tell me how to turn it off?

Comment: File ---- Settings --------- Build, Execution, Deployment  -------  Gradle.

here you shall see the "Offline work" uncheck that